# Intermittent error "Not authorized to access Exact Online" when accessing XML topic Settings of Exact Online

Tags: exact-online, invantive-query-tool, invantive-sql

During querying on Exact Online, I sometimes get an intermittent error in the Invantive Query Tool:

```
Not authorized to access Exact Online.
Please check that you have access to the administration and have licensed a module for the data object 'Settings'.
```

For some errors, we automatically retry the operation, for instance when the OAuth token expires.

At this moment we can not reliably detect this error since the text varies per language and has no message code. However, when you try a few more times without changing anything, the access on the Exact Online XML topic 'Settings' proceeds successfully. Retrying without carefully knowing what is wrong is not a reliable approach since an update can be applied then multiple times.

How do I reliably detect this type of error so I can appropriate automatic corrective measures?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution you want to share, or is this question out of date?

Comment: No, it seems that the problem want away by magic. Or a patch on the server side :-)